# Recover using lost+found

Tags: 14.04

After using the command

```
e2fsck -f -b 32768 -y /dev/sda5
```

I recover my partition, but it only has a folder (lost+found), with a lot of files, how can I recover my files from it?

I tried using fsck but gave

> `e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014) e2fsck: Is a directory while trying to
>   open /media/ubuntu/7bfaa5d7-ac18-43b6-80ea-cf6dfd50781f
>
> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid
>   ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really
>   contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or
>   something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try
>   running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
>       e2fsck -b 8193   or
>       e2fsck -b 32768

Please, I really need this files

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover data from the lost+found folder?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175945/how-to-recover-data-from-the-lostfound-folder)